# setAuthors - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key cannot be 0

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

In my XPages app I am trying to set an Item as Authors type but I get an unexpected key cannot be 0 message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key cannot be 0
at org.openntf.domino.impl.DominoReferenceCache.put(DominoReferenceCache.java:148)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.WrapperFactory.recacheLotusObject(WrapperFactory.java:316)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.BaseThreadSafe.setDelegate(BaseThreadSafe.java:75)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.resurrect(Item.java:1064)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Base.getDelegate(Base.java:475)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.getFlagSet(Item.java:105)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.isNames(Item.java:629)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.hasFlag(Item.java:1086)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.isReadersNamesAuthors(Item.java:1101)
at org.openntf.domino.impl.Item.setAuthors(Item.java:731)
at org.acme.projectx.dao.MatterDominoDAO.setAccessFields(MatterDominoDAO.java:1875)
```

Here is where I am trying to set the property:

```
matter.setCommAuthors(getAuthorsCommittee(matter));
if (null != matter.getCommAuthors()) {
    fieldName = "CommAuthors";
    doc.replaceItemValue(fieldName, matter.getCommAuthors());
    Item authorFieldCommittee = doc.replaceItemValue(fieldName, matter.getCommAuthors());
    authorFieldCommittee.setAuthors(true);
}
```

Anyone has a clue why the error message pops up?

Comment: What type is "matter" and what data type is returned by "matter.getCommAuthors()" ? It seems to be something which cannot be used as field value

Comment: Why are you calling `doc.replaceItemValue` twice with the same field name? You only need the second of those calls if you only want to set the one field, though I don't think that would fix the error.

Comment: Just guessing, since I'm not familiar with the OpenNTF Domino API. I'd try to comment out the line doc.replaceItemValue(fieldName, matter.getCommAuthors()) in your code. As already mentioned by Scott, that line is redundant. It effectively creates a Java object that is never referenced by a variable in your code, plus a back-end object associated with it. If memory serves, the OpenNTF API contains some sort of garbage collection that frees the back-end object without the programmer having to explicitely call recycle(). Who knows, maybe that mechanism is causing the error in your code.

Comment: Patrick, did the comments help you?

Comment: Patrick, did the comments from the helpful community help you find an answer?